# How to show only the text of radio box in html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a calendar with just HTML and CSS, but when the user clicks on a day, it changes some property.

I was planning on using a radio button for each day. However with the radio button, it will show up a little box.

So my idea is to use `<input type="radio" id="" name="" value="">` each day and then only one day is selected.

Can someone help me? This is how my calendar looks like:

[image: calendar]

```
<div id="speed">
<table style="width:25%">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><a href="12.php"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></a></td>
        <td colspan="2">January</td>
        <td><a href="2.php"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sun</td>
        <td>Mon</td>
        <td>Tue</td>
        <td>Wen</td>
        <td>Thu</td>
        <td>Fri</td>
        <td>Sat⠀</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="gray">27</td>
        <td class="gray">28</td>
        <td class="gray">29</td>
        <td class="gray">30</td>
        <td class="gray">31</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>17</td>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>24</td>
        <td>25</td>
        <td>26</td>
        <td>27</td>
        <td>28</td>
        <td>29</td>
        <td>30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>31</td>
        <td class="gray">1</td>
        <td class="gray">2</td>
        <td class="gray">3</td>
        <td class="gray">4</td>
        <td class="gray">5</td>
        <td class="gray">6</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Add a label element for each day, then set the radio button to `appearance:none;` and when you click a label it will select the radio button. You can then style the label by using the selector `input:checked + label` (input that is checked, + next, label)
Made a codepen to show this in action: https://codepen.io/z-/pen/dyWpYoJ

Answer (score 2):

You can hide, radio button radio manually using css.

```
[type='radio'] {
    display: none; 
}

<input type="radio" value="1">
<input type="radio" value="2">
<input type="radio" value="3">
<input type="radio" value="4">
<input type="radio" value="1">
```